# Как вывести на точечный график (scatter plot) имя каждой точки (имя содержится в отдельной колонке таблицы)?

Tags: python

Есть таблица из множества отрезков:
имя точки Х, её координаты X_x, Y_x, имя точки У, её координаты X_y, Y_y
Не получается вывести на точечный график имя для точки Х и точки У.

сейчас код выглядит следующим образом:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,10), dpi = 200) 
x1 = acc_V_in_R['X_x']
y1 = acc_V_in_R['Y_x']
x2 = acc_V_in_R['X_y']
y2 = acc_V_in_R['Y_y']
plt.scatter(x1, y1)
plt.scatter(x2, y2)
labels1 = acc_V_in_R['no2006']
labels2 = acc_V_in_R['no2006_1']
for i in range(len(x1)):
   plt.annotate(labels1[i],  (x1[i], y1[i] + 0.2))
   plt.annotate(labels2[i], (x2[i], y2[i] + 0.2))
plt.show()
```

Python выдает ошибку.

Данный код проходит, если по ходу скрипта таблицу сохранить в csv файл и вызвать его через read_csv, но хочется избежать таких лишних шагов.

Чего не достает или в чем ошибка? файл xlsx для примера в приложении.
[исходная таблица](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19SA3Y_XTlYaPQzdkrZx8SyBmzb3Ndrqj/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=105326785031219603112&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: а изначально ваша таблица в каком виде используется? это датафрейм pandas?

Comment: да, было бы неплохо выкладывать текст ошибки.

Comment: да, pd.dataframe.

Comment: Используйте .iloc для индексации по порядку. Просто скобки аналогичны использованию .loc, это обращение по индексам датафоейма, а в индексах у вас может быть что угодно, например пропуски в номерах. Плохо, что вы ошибку в вопросе не приводите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, вы неверно обращаетесь к данным в датафрейме - просто по индексу списка к ним обращаться нельзя. Воспользуйтесь методом `itertiuples`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("1505_poi_1.xlsx - Sheet1.csv", index_col=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,10), dpi = 200)
plt.scatter(df["X_x"], df["Y_x"])
plt.scatter(df["X_y"], df["Y_y"])
for r in df.itertuples():    
    ax.annotate(r[1], (r[2], r[3]))
    ax.annotate(r[4], (r[5], r[6]))    

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Индексы в вашем датафрейме идут не по порядку (см. колонку `index`):

| index | no2006 | X_x | Y_x | no2006_1 | X_y | Y_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2529 | 13 | 317035 | 4785929 | 217 | 317661 | 4785562 |
| 2534 | 62 | 317140 | 4785885 | 217 | 317661 | 4785562 |
| 675 | 217 | 317661 | 4785562 | 85 | 317515 | 4785504 |
| 2981 | 217 | 317661 | 4785562 | 270 | 318092 | 4785186 |
| 3878 | 270 | 318092 | 4785186 | 342 | 318010 | 4784834 |
| 9313 | 557 | 317978 | 4784535 | 934 | 319002 | 4784335 |
| 6264 | 217 | 317661 | 4785562 | 476 | 318016 | 4784787 |
| 6283 | 643 | 317943 | 4784286 | 476 | 318016 | 4784787 |
| 7377 | 797 | 318749 | 4784323 | 557 | 317978 | 4784535 |
| 9629 | 643 | 317943 | 4784286 | 964 | 317122 | 4783752 |
| 10639 | 934 | 319002 | 4784335 | 1038 | 317465 | 4783869 |
| 7329 | 217 | 317661 | 4785562 | 557 | 317978 | 4784535 |

Обращение к через `[]` аналогично обращению по **индексу датафрейма** (или индексу серии, если это отдельный столбец, взятый из датафрейма), то есть `.loc[]` в современной пандасовской нотации. Индексов `0`, `1` и т.д. в вашем датафрейме нет, вот и выходит ошибка. Используйте `.iloc[]` для обращения к строкам датафрейма (или элементам серии) без использования индекса, а просто по порядку:

```py
   plt.annotate(labels1.iloc[i], (x1.iloc[i], y1.iloc[i] + 0.2))
   plt.annotate(labels2.iloc[i], (x2.iloc[i], y2.iloc[i] + 0.2))
```